# how to applying nunique table of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe

```
   City  Gender
0  A     M
1  B     F
2  C     F
3  A     M
4  A     M
5  B     F
```

then I want to use .nunique on City column to know something like how many contents in that table occupy the top 2 positions

I learnt from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html
and I have tried to run this

```
df_dataset['City'].nunique()
```

but something is doesn't add up

Comment: what do you mean by 'top 2 positions'? Do you mean the 2 most frequent cities?

Comment: @sophocles yes, if it comes to my dataframe. I think the result should show
A  3
B  2
C  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)?:

```
>>> df['City'].value_counts().head(2)

Out[34]: 
A    3
B    2
```

`head(2)` will just return the top 2.

Comment: no, from what I see from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/, I think .value_count and .unique have different function
I mean. can I go with .nunique?

Comment: ```nunique()``` will give you the number of unique items in a column, so the answer in your case would be ```3```. ```unique()``` would give you back an array of the 3 unique items in your column, i.e. ```array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)``` . ```value_counts()```, as illustrated above, would give you your expected output. Consequently, of course you can go with ```nunique()``` but as explained it won't give you your expected output.